# como faço pra criar um botão para incrementar mais um

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, sou novo com javascript e estou tendo uma dificuldade em criar um botão aonde minha sempre muda meu h2 pra +1, segue meu codigo:

```
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">SENHA</h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">0</h2>

    

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <button id="count" >Nova Senha</button>
    </div>
    <br>

    <form style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" value="IMPRIMIR" onClick="window.print()"/></form>
</body>
</html>
```

var cont = 0;
function contador(){
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

```
    cont++;
```

}

Preciso que do 0 comece a somar +1 toda vez que clicar em nova senha, alguem sabe o que devo fazer pra conserta o código ??

Comment: A função `contador` não é chamada no seu código; e se for, só altera a variável `cont`, que não é usada no código.

Comment: Como assim não é chamado no meu codigo ? Eu chamo ela no <script>

Comment: No código que postou na pergunta ela não é chamada. Se ela realmente é no seu código, peço que elabore então um [mcve] demonstrando o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teu código deveria ficar assim:

```html
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">SENHA</h1>
    <h2 id="count" style="text-align: center;">0</h2>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <button onclick="contar()">Nova Senha</button>
    </div>
    <br>

    <form style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" value="IMPRIMIR" onClick="window.print()"/></form>

    <script>
        let count = 0
        const countElement = document.getElementById("count")
        
        function contar() {
            count++
            countElement.textContent = count
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Beleza mas qual foi teu erro?

Tu simplismente pegou o button e o h2 mas não fez NADA com eles. Tu deveria ter colocado no botão a ação de `contador` no `onclick` porque se não vai acontecer quando?

Outra coisa depois de fazer a função ser chamada tu tem que colocar o valor do contador no teu h2. Então tu faz `h2.textContent = ValorQueTuQuer` e automaticamente o html vai atualizar com esse novo valor.

```
var cont = 0;
function contador(){
        let button = document.getElementById("btn");
        let h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
        
        cont++;
}
```